# Разное поведение шрифта Rex на декстопе и мобилке

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Проблема следующая: при использовании шрифта 'Rex', Arial, sans-serif, происходит разное отображение стилей на десктопе и мобильном устройстве (именно устройстве; на десктопе в браузере в мобильной версии этот баг воспроизвести не получилось).

Детали. Есть блок с заглавной буквой. Даны стили, чтобы заглавная буква была с центре круга со своим бэкгрундом. Центрирование может быть, как за счёт lh, либо через df, jcc, aic. Вроде, всё хорошо. Но стоит посмотреть результат с телефона и планшета (проверял на ipod и разных смартфонах на андроид), как видим, что не произошло вертикального центрирования. Помогает лишь отключение данного шрифта.
В полном замешательстве. Какие есть идеи у знатоков?

Для наглядности привожу код, но к сожалению, шрифт Rex через cdn подключить не получилось, поэтому только если попробуете локально.

https://codepen.io/drsg/pen/rNaRBqe

```
.letter А

.letter {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;

    color: black;
    font-family: 'Rex', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;

    background-color: gold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Дропните на условный яндекс диск файл с подключаемыми вами шрифтами.

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка в самом шрифте. У меня получилось исправить ее, прогнав файлы шрифта через [Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) со следующими настройками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на Subsetting: если не настраивать его руками, из шрифта почему-то удалялись то латинские, то кириллические символы. Более того, данный шрифт на многих ресурсах битый и возникают другие проблемы с отображением.